# How can I disable the air conditioner beeper?

Tags: electrical, repair, air-conditioning, sounds

I bought this model: MFL69782201 (User manual PDF http://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=S45tMoOwlLqIpW2lkIGLfA)
It is a split dual inverter.

The problem is there is no way to disable the beep that happens every time we press a button in the remote control. I contacted the manufacturer and they say "it is how it works and is impossible to disable the beep".

The noise is very annoying, mostly in the morning, and mostly because I live in an apartment. I don't want that noise to cause trouble with my neighbors.

I know if I make a hole on it somewhere I will be able to reach the beeper and cut it out or block it enough to lower the beep volume in a hardware way.

But I can't find a maintenance manual for it, so I don't know where to cut. Yes I am aware about warranty, but... The beep is so horrible that I avoid using it as much I can. I feel like I bought the wrong product...

- Has anyone done that kind of thing?
- Did it work?
- Where can I find such maintenance manual?
- Cut or damage the utterly annoying beeper can cause other problems on the circuit board?

Comment: why would you cut a hole in the AC cabinet? ... how did that thought even enter your head? ... just take off the cover, find the beeper and cover it with tape

Comment: You could just set it and leave it set, too. No need to press a button = no beeps.

Comment: @Ecnerwal when I turn it on, it "sings" loudly for about 3s... If I need to change the temperature it makes a loud beep for every button press, I mean, I cant just set and leave it, I need to have access to these controls at anytime.

Comment: @jsotola mmm... I lift a movable panel but I couldnt see the control board. To take off the whole cover I would have to have access to the backside of it where are the screws, but it is on the wall. It is already installed (of course) and I am scared of messing with the gas tubes that connect to it. But I will look more to see if there is something safe that I could do, what a mess, I should have bought from some other manufacturer...

Comment: the link you posted requires a membership ... please post a picture of the front of the AC

Comment: is there a display board? ... that is where the beeper would be

Comment: @jsotola thx, I didnt see the pdf was not good... (only showed the initial pages), I changed the link to a pdf download (I cant find english version tho). I will lift the panel and take a photo tomorrow as right now it is 00:21am and I cant make much noise moving stairs around to reach it :)

Comment: Your indoor unit will have two or more screws (often near the blower) that hold the cover. The cover in most split units can be removed easily without messing with the gas pipes or dismounting the whole unit from the wall. Watch some videos on how split ac units are serviced. [Take off the cover](https://youtu.be/texGW7Gi3fg?t=367) and maybe you can find the exact part that makes the beep and do something about it. If you are not able to remove the cover then call the service guys (they clean the coils) and when they arrive ask them to do something about the beep.

Answer (score 1):

[Attention, do not try this w/o a electronics technician that can give you warranties that your air conditioner will not be damaged! You have been warned!]

A few months later...

I talked to a friend that understand electronics.
He said that removing the buzzer completely could not cause any problems.

But before trying that drastic solution, first I tried just to remove the buzzer cover to try to put something inside the buzzer to lower the noise.
But then... to my surprise, the buzzer came out completely and cleanly w/o damaging the circuit board (probably it was weakly soldered), by luck I guess...

I've been using the air conditioner w/o noises since then.

So... for that model it is not causing any trouble that I can detect to the date.
**This doesn't mean there is no problem there!!!**
I am just sharing what happened and is apparently working w/o problems, but I do not understand electronics myself so I cannot explain if it is or is not causing problems!!!
Also, the buzzer is used to provide diagnostic data thru a cell phone call by making noises like a fax I guess, so that functionality became unavailable until I plug the buzzer back again.

**If you want to try this, talk to some friend that understand electronics first, and better ask him to manipulate the buzzer so that you wont damage it, and if possible ask him to test if the circuit could be failing somehow so he can solder it (or something else less irritating, may be a led?) back if something looks wrong.**

I risked myself damaging the air conditioner... totally out of real despair, because of the absurdly irritating noise, I should never have bought that model initially at all!!! (and will never buy again w/o being sure it is possible to disable the noises w/o risking damaging it).

I do not recommend doing it w/o someone that understand the electronics of the model of your specific air conditioner, ask a technician to help you tweak the hardware, and to give you warranty in case some problem happens, that would be the most safe way for sure.

If you think I could share this text in a way ppl will understand the risks better, say so or edit it please. I am just sharing that it is working but I cannot guarantee there is no problems...

If you understand electronics, you could explain us why it is apparently not causing any troubles? or even better, what problems may happen if I keep it w/o the buzzer?

Comment: It's like a light bulb. If it burns out, your toilets will continue to flush properly. The only purpose of the bulb is to turn on when provided with power. Similarly, the only purpose of the beeper is to beep when it receives an electrical impulse. If it doesn't beep, the compressor doesn't care, and neither does the blower motor or the filter.